# Connecting SeekBar to MediaPlayer isn't working

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, seekbar

I've been following a tutorial to implement a `SeekBar` to my app but it isn't working. Here's how I'm trying to do it.

```
public void run(){
    int currentPosition = 0;
    int total = player.getDuration();
    sBar.setMax(total);

    while (player.isPlaying()) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            currentPosition = player.getCurrentPosition();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        sBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
    }
}
```

`sBar` is the `SeekBar` which I declared as a global variable.

Now the problem is that there was nowhere mentioned in the tutorial where to then call this run method? I tried calling it right after the `MediaPlayer` is started but it isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a completely different approach to this and it worked. Here's how I've done it now:

```
Runnable run = new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run() {
        seekBarUpdate();
    }

};

public void seekBarUpdate(){
    sBar.setMax(player.getDuration());
    sBar.setProgress(player.getCurrentPosition());
    seekHandler.postDelayed(run, 25);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously meant to be put in a Thread object-  its an infinite loop that sleeps for a second at a time.  It can't go on the UI thread or it will freeze your app.

Comment: Also, he shouldn't be using a thread anyway. A handler that is set to post a message each second can accomplish the same thing with less overhead.

Comment: So it seems like I approached this in a whole wrong way. Could you give me a better, more effective solution to accomplish this? A better tutorial could do it; I've been doing research for a few hours and I just can't find any good example on how to do this, I'm left clueless.